# Exponential distribution - When will the patient be treated?

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

A patient is sitting in the waiting room of a doctor's office. We assume that its waiting time in minutes is exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda = 0.2$. Within what time will the patient be treated with probability $0.9$?
The patient waited $5$ minutes without being called. How long does he have to wait with probability $0.9$?

$$$$

I have done the following: 
$$P(X\leq x)=1-e^{-\lambda x}\Rightarrow 0.9=1-e^{-0.2x}  \Rightarrow e^{-0.2x} =0.1 \Rightarrow x \approx 11.513$$ 
Within the first $11.5$ minutes the patient will be treated with probability $0.9$.

Is at the second question "The patient waited $5$ minutes without being called. How long does he have to wait with probability $0.9$?" the answer "He has to wait for 11,5-5 minutes."? Or do we have to calculate something else here?

Comment: For the second question, the exponential distribution has the memoryless property, making the answer about $11.513$ or $16.513$ depending on when you start measuring

Comment: Does this mean that the probability, which is equal to 0.9, that he will be treated within the first 11,5 minutes doesn't depent on when he starts to wait? @Henry

Comment: No.  It means that having waited five minutes without treatment, the future distribution of waiting times is the same as it was originally.  So the patient should expect to wait an average of $11.516$ *more* minutes in addition to the $5$ minutes already waited

Comment: The formula is $P(X>s+t|X>t) = P(X>s)$. We have that the probability that he has to wait is $0.9$ which is also equal to $P(X\leq 11,513)$. Since the patients waits $5$ minues, we have that $t=5$. So, we have the following: $$P(X\leq 11,513)=1-P(X> 11,513)=1-P(X>11,513+5|X>5) $$ Is this correct? Or do I apply the formula wrong? @Henry

Comment: You can accept the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Yes, the two questions are indeed independent.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

An important property of the exponential distribution is that *it lacks memory*, that is, if $X$ has an exponential distribution, then, $$P(X>s+t|X>t) = P(X>s)$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: So, is in this case $t=5$ minutes? Does this mean that the probability, which is equal to 0.9, that he will be treated within the first 11,5 minutes doesn't depent on when he starts to wait?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, $t=5$. So, calculate $s$. Them find, $P(X>s)$.

Comment: The probability that the patient will wait $s+5$ minutes is the same as the probability that the patient will wait $s+5$ minutes  given that he is still waiting after $t=5$ minutes. 
$$$$ 
So, we have that $P(X>s+t|X>t) = P(X>s)=0,9 \Rightarrow e^{-0.2s}=0.9\Rightarrow -0.2s=\ln 0.9\Rightarrow s\approx 0.526803$. $$$$ Or is the probability $0.9$ equal to $P(X\leq s)$ ?

Comment: Or do I use the formula wrong?

Comment: I got stuck right now... Is it $P(X>s)=0,9$ or $P(X\leq s)=0,9$ ?

Comment: It is $P(X>s)=0.9$.

Comment: The patient is waiting already for t = 5 min. The probability that he will wait in total more than s+t = s+5 min. is equal to 0,9. So, we get $$0,9=P(X>s+5 \mid X>5)=P(X>s)\Rightarrow 0.9=e^{-0.2s}\Rightarrow \ln 0.9=-0.2s\Rightarrow s\approx 0.526803$$ So, in total the patient will wait $s+t=0.526803+5=5.526803$ minutes?

Comment: Yes, @MaryStar you have got the correct value of $s$.

Comment: But I haven't really undersood that at the first part I have calculated that within the first 11.5 minutes the patient will be treated with probability 0.9 and now we find that the patient has to wait in total about 5.5 minutes with probability 0.9 Or are these two questions independent?